# How to let htop display as much as possible cores in one row

Tags: ubuntu, htop

My workstation have 256 logic cores, and it seems `htop` can only display 4 cores usage in one row. So there are 64 rows to display cpu usage, thus I can't see any process information in `htop`. And I do need to observe CPU usage. So I wonder if there is a method to let `htop` display 8 cores or even 10 cores usage in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`htop` version 3.0.0 and later allow the CPU metrics to be split into 16 columns. To set that up, press <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>→</kbd> until you reach the “Available meters” column, move down to “CPUs (1-8/16)”, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use the cursor keys to move the new entry to the desired position, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again; do the same with “CPUs (9-16/16)”. To remove the old meters (“CPUs (1&2/4)” and “CPUs (3&4/4)”), select them with the cursor keys and press <kbd>Del</kbd>.

This version of `htop` is only available in Ubuntu 22.04 or later; in earlier versions, you’d be better off removing the CPU meters entirely, or using only the “CPU average” meter (which shows the average usage across all cores):

[image: htop showing average CPU, memory, swap, tasks, load average, uptime]